# onmousemove event not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript

I have coding for onmousemove event working well in Firefox and IE but not in Chrome:

```
         var mouse;
         function storeMouse(e) {
             if (!e) e = window.event;
             mouse = { clientX: e.clientX, clientX: e.clientY };
         }

         function test(e) {
             alert(mouse.clientX);
             if (mouse.clientX < 150) {
                 var agree = confirm("Are you sure to leave this page");
                 if (!agree) {
                     return false;
                 }
                 else {

                 }
             }
         }
```

Comment: Where are you calling storeMouse. We just see the function definition...

Comment: window.event is actually an IE thing, I think... Did you try looking into  window.addeventListener?

Comment: I would take a look at [QuirksMode's MouseEvent page](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html) to examine cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: There isn't even mention of `mousemove` in the code posted. Please edit your question.

Comment: Just to help any people in the future finding this through google: If you for some reason have 'Emulate touch events' on, disable this. That took some time for me to figure out and wasnt fun at all.

Answer (score 2):

Problem at line 4: Duplicate mouse.clientX